# A* algorithm doesn't find the shortest path when I put a big wall

Tags: c++, a-star

My implementation of the A* algorithm doesn't guarantee the shortest path when there is a big wall covering the board. Does it have something to do with the calculations of the costs?

I provided a picture for you to understand what I'm saying. As you can see in the picture, it doesn't find the shortest path

[image]

Heuristic func:

```
double calc_heuristic(T src, T end, std::map<T, std::pair<sf::Vector2f, bool>> &tileCoords_){
    sf::Vector2f srcLoc(tileCoords_[src].first);
    sf::Vector2f endLoc(tileCoords_[end].first);
    return std::abs(srcLoc.x - endLoc.x) + std::abs(srcLoc.y - endLoc.y);
}
```

Algorithm:

```
int count = 0;
std::set<std::pair<std::pair<double, uint32_t>, T>> open_set;
open_set.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(0, count), start));
std::map<T, T> came_from;
std::map<T, uint32_t> g_score;
std::map<T, double> f_score;
for (auto n : adjList)
    g_score[n.first] = INT_MAX;
g_score[start] = 0;
for (auto n : adjList)
    f_score[n.first] = INT_MAX;
f_score[start] = calc_heuristic(start, end, tileCoords_);
std::vector<T> open_set_v {start};
std::vector<T> path_;

while (!open_set.empty()){
    auto current_pair = *(open_set.begin());
    T current = current_pair.second;

    open_set.erase(open_set.begin());
    auto it1 = std::find(open_set_v.begin(), open_set_v.end(), current);
    open_set_v.erase(it1);

    if (current == end)
        break;

    for (auto neighbor : adjList[current]){
        uint32_t temp_g_score = g_score[current] + 1;
        if (temp_g_score < g_score[neighbor.first]){
            came_from[neighbor.first] = current;
            g_score[neighbor.first] = temp_g_score;
            f_score[neighbor.first] = temp_g_score + calc_heuristic(neighbor.first, end, tileCoords_);
            if (std::find(open_set_v.begin(), open_set_v.end(), neighbor.first) == open_set_v.end()){
                count++;
                open_set.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(f_score[neighbor.first], count), neighbor.first));
                open_set_v.push_back(neighbor.first);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the heuristic is a correct implementation of [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) then it's not your problem. When the algorithm gets stuck on the wall and starts moving left it should start re-looking at the starting path. The wrong path is supposed to get lower priority due to the doubling back.

Comment: What's the difference between white and light blue tiles? The blue ones aren't a lot cheaper, are they, such that that path actually is optimal?

Comment: @JohnKugelman blue tiles are the visited nodes

Comment: @JohnKugelman when it hits the wall, the left tiles have lower f costs so it's priority is higher?

Comment: You don't look for the shortest path, you stop when you find the first path. Instead of going depth first (keep looking to the right) you should do a breadth first search. expand from your current node to all your neighbours and then from those neighbours to their (unvisited) neighbours etc.

Comment: @PepijnKramer what should i change with my code?

Comment: Have a look at this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: @PepijnKramer how does it know if it will use a flood fill. not sure how to do that

Comment: The idea is that during "floodfill" you also keep track of the level of recursion and the moment you hit the "exit" this depth will be your minimal distance.

Comment: @PepijnKramer A* should already been doing that. It's essentially a flood fill with a heuristic to help aim the fill towards the goal. If correctly implemented with an [admissible heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), when A* reaches the goal there's no need to keep looking because it's guaranteed to have found the shortest path.

Comment: @JohnKugelman still can't find a solution to my problem